# Unable to run WP81 unit tests with VSTest.Console.exe

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, vstest

I am trying to run Windows Phone 8.1 unit tests from the command line using the [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx). I have created a new Windows Phone 8.1 unit test project in VS 2013 (Update 4):

[image]

The unit test is discovered in Visual Studio and I am able to run it successfully:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

The next step is to create a new `AppPackage` from my test project which generated the desired `.appx` file. Then I tried to run the unit test contained in this file using the following command:

```
vstest.console.exe /InIsolation /settings:Test.runsettings UnitTestApp1_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug.appx
```

where `Test.runsettings` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <MSPhoneTest>
    <TargetDevice>Emulator WVGA</TargetDevice>
  </MSPhoneTest>
</RunSettings>
```

This command started the emulator but fails with this error:

> Error: Installation of package 'D:\work\WP81UnitTestApp\UnitTestApp1\AppPackages\UnitTestApp1_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug_Test\UnitTestApp1_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug.appx' failed with Error: (0xFFFFFFFF) To run unit tests for a Windows Phone app, the app must target Windows Phone 8 or higher..

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that I was using a wrong emulator name in my `Test.runsettings` file. Changing it to this made my tests work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <MSPhoneTest>
    <TargetDevice>Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB</TargetDevice>
  </MSPhoneTest>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: do these runsettings need to be part of the unit test project or do you manually place these along side your appx?